# postgreSQL Error inserción en la tabla viola la llave foránea

Tags: postgresql, foranea

Estoy intentando meter datos a la siguiente tabla pero cuando voy a ejecutar la orden me sale el mensaje:
ERROR:  inserción o actualización en la tabla «person» viola la llave foránea «fk_person»
DETAIL:  La llave (house_id)=(1) no está presente en la tabla «house».

Los datos a insertar serían : (1, 'Euan', 'Abercrombie', 1) la inserción sería en la tabla (PERSON)

```
CREATE TABLE HOUSE( 
    id numeric(1),
    nombre varchar (50) not null    
);

ALTER TABLE HOUSE
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_HOUSE PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE HOUSE 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_HOUSE FOREIGN KEY (HEAD_TEACHER) REFERENECES PERSON (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELTE NO ACTION;

CREATE TABLE PERSON(
    id numeric(4),
    first_name varchar(50),
    last_name varchar(50),
    house_id numeric(1),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Person FOREIGN KEY (house_id) REFERENCES HOUSE (id) ON UPDATE cascade ON DELETE no action
);
ALTER TABLE PERSON
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_PERSON PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No entiendo cuál es el problema, si claramente te dice lo que está mal, qué parte no entiendes? edita la pregunta y agrega algunos datos de cada tabla para que te ayudemos

Comment: Tienes que insertar primero en `HOUSE`, pues tu FK hace referencia a esa tabla y seguro no tiene el valor que estan insertando en `PERSON`

Comment: El problema es que si intento meter datos en la tabla HOUSE me aparece el mismo error y no me deja meter ni en una ni en otra... El problema que tengo es que aunque me ponga el error que es no se como resolverlo, los datos los estoy intentando meter con INSERT TO PERSON
(las propiedades de perdón) VALUES (aquí dentro los valores)